# Twine doesn't upload folder

Tags: python, module, filesystems, pypi, twine

When I upload to PyPi, the `extension` folder wasn't added, only the outer python files were.

#### File Structure:

```
Main Project Folder
└──Actual Module Folder
   └──__init__.py
   └──file1.py
   └──extension
      └──__init__.py
      └──file2
      └──file3
      └──file4
└──.gitignore
└──setup.py
```

Contents of `Actual Module Folder\__init__.py`

```py
from .file1 import *
from extension import *
```

Contents of `Actual Module Folder\extension\__init__.py`

```py
from file2 import *
from file3 import *
from file4 import *
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a `minifest.in` file in top folder and there add these line `recursive-include Actual Module Folder *`